# Is there a way to use data.table in R for applying a function to elements of a dataset by binary id?

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a function I would like to apply to a column of a very large dataset, but dependent on the id of another column. What I mean is that if I have a dataset like so:

```
Time   ID
5.5    1
6.2    0
8.4    1
10.0   1
```

I would like to apply `function1` to the `time` entry if the `ID` is 0 and apply `function2` to the `time` entry if the `ID` is 1. Hence, if `function1` is x^2 and `function2` is x, then I would like to get a returned matrix of:

```
Time   ID
5.5    1
38.44  0
8.4    1
10.0   0
```

Currently, I have tried to use a for-loop like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(matrix)){
  if(matrix$id[i]==0)
  value <- matrix$Time^2
  else
......
```

However, this is going very slowly as my dataset consists of over 50 million rows. I have been trying to figure out a way of using data.table but am not sure if it is doable. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As your second function basically is not changing the value of "Time", we can assign (`:=`) the `Time^2` when `ID==0`

```
setDT(df1)[ID==0, Time:= Time^2][]
#    Time ID
#1:  5.50  1
#2: 38.44  0
#3:  8.40  1
#4: 10.00  1
```

Suppose your function2 is 'Time^3', one option would be `ifelse`

```
setDT(df1)[, Time:= ifelse(ID==1, Time^3, Time^2)]
```

Or as suggested by @thelatemail, an option using `switch` for multiple functions

```
fun1 <- function(x) x^2
fun2 <- function(x) x^3
setDT(df1)[, Time:=switch(as.character(.BY),`0`=fun1(Time),
           `1`=fun2(Time)), by=ID][]
```

Or

```
setDT(df1)[, Time:= if(.BY==0) fun1(Time) else fun2(Time), by=ID][]
```

Comment: `dt[, Timenew:=switch(as.character(.BY),\`0\`=fun1(Time),\`1\`=fun2(Time)), by=ID]` as an extensible option maybe?

Comment: Or maybe simpler: `dt[, Timenew:=if(.BY==0) fun1(Time) else fun2(Time), by=ID]`

Comment: I was thinking about the `if` `else`, but somehow I messed up the code before. Thanks

Comment: the issue for me was avoiding having multiple `:=` assignments - this seems to get around it.,